# Prove that |f|(x) = |f(x)| has a limit

Tags: analysis

I need to show that $|f| : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by |f|(x) = |f(x)| has a limit as $x$ tends to $x_0$ and that $\lim_{||x|| \rightarrow x_0} |f(x)| = |\lim_{||x|| \rightarrow x_0} f(x)|$.

I know that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there $\exists \delta > 0$ such that if $||x-x_0| \Rightarrow ||f(x)-f(x_0)|| < \epsilon$. But how do I move on from here?

My textbook says that f(x) tends to c as ||x|| tends to infinity if $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there is a $K > 0$ such that if $||x|| > K$ then $|f(x)-c| < \epsilon$.

I know that I should use the triangle inequality but I don't know how.

Thanks!

Comment: $||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|$.

Comment: Hi Kabo. Thanks. However I am not very good at Analysis 1 so can you please elaborate? Should I set a = f(x) and b = c? Note further that $c = \lim_{||x|| \rightarrow x_0} f(x)$. Thanks!

Comment: Take $a=f(x)$ and $b=f(x_0)$